# ExceptionManagement Error

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

Am Getting Error msg like

> The event source ExceptionManagerInternalException does not exist and
>   cannot be created with the current permissions.

Code using in my `web.config`

```
<section name="exceptionManagement" type="Microsoft.ApplicationBlocks.ExceptionManagement.ExceptionManagerSectionHandler,Microsoft.ApplicationBlocks.ExceptionManagement"/>
  <exceptionManagement mode="on">
    <publisher assembly="ExceptionManagement" type="Zerone.ExceptionManagement.ExceptionXMLPublisher" exceptionFormat="xml" fileName="c:\ALAE\"/>
  </exceptionManagement>
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you post the code that _consumes_ that entry?

Answer (score 8):

In a DOS window with admin permissions run:

```
eventcreate /t error /id 1000 /so ExceptionManagerInternalException /l application /d "new src ExceptionManagerInternalException in application log"

eventcreate /t error /id 1000 /so ExceptionManagerPublishedException /l application /d "new src ExceptionManagerPublishedException in application log"
```

This solve my problem with a client application, but should work in ASP-net

[Reference here](http://www.darrenmcleod.com/mydnn/Home/tabid/36/EntryId/29/Microsoft-ApplicationBlocks-ExceptionManagement-The-event-source-x-does-not-exist-error.aspx).